# Creating a new project in a Solution through Nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I currently have an application that produces two nuget packages. The first package is an SDK and therefore contains a bunch of dlls and the second packages up some test code that demonstrates how to use the SDK as well as having a dependancy on the first package.

I would like to be able to create an empty solution in Visual Studio and then install the second package(the test code one). This should in turn create a new project in the solution, copy all the test source code and reference all the dlls from the first package. Is this possible to do using nuget?

Currently this does not work as I get a warning that it could not target any projects in the solution. To get round this I have to create an empty project in the solution and then install the second package to this. This does work and it grabs the dlls from the first package and the source code from the second however it is not very intuitive since you first have to create an empty project. This in turn means you also have to know which type of project to create etc.

In the future we plan to have different packages targeting console, winform and wpf apps etc. so to save us a headache it would be nice if there is someway to create the project automatically through the package.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but then you have to create a Visual Studio template by building an Extension (VSIX).

It's quite a lot of work but this way you can create project and/or solution templates that already contain a folder structure, classes and NuGet packages.

Take a look at this MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx and this article from the NuGet documentation: http://docs.nuget.org/create/packages-in-visual-studio-templates

Be warned it is an intensive job.

Comment: Yeah does look to be a fair bit of work but probably worth it in the long run if it can save some confusion for our clients!. Thanks for the links will give them a proper read over